# C#: restricting Print Screen of my Application

Tags: c#, winforms, printscreen

I am making a Test Engine
so i want to restrict PrintScreen of my application

Comment: Does it have a secret rocket design?  You can't restrict it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent print screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448106/how-do-i-prevent-print-screen)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to not have a non-trivial UI.

Comment: Not necessarily. The UI and text could be rendered in a single color, no borders, etc.