# Is it possible to restrict the user to take snapshot of screen in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, screenshot

I have an application developed in C#. I need a mechanism to restrict the user to take screen shot when the application window on top.
Is it possible to restrict the user to take screenshot??

I have already listen the PrtScr Button to restrict the built in mechanism of windows to take screenshot.

But if user uses some capturing application to capture the skin.. I think there might be some windows event or such like thing, which is triggered when a a screenshot is taken. I need to know about it. Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already discussed/answered on SO: [How do I prevent print screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448106/how-do-i-prevent-print-screen)

try searching a bit before asking! ;-)

Comment: I've searched but didn't find. THank you.

Answer (score 0):

In windows form application, Use this code in form keyup event,

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PrintScreen)
            {
                Clipboard.Clear();
            }
```

form keypreview should be true.