# Best Practices For Secure APIs?

Tags: php, ajax, api, openid, oauth

Let's say I have a website that has a lot of information on our products.  I'd like some of our customers (including us!) to be able to look up our products for various methods, including:

1)  Pulling data from AJAX calls that return data in cool, JavaScripty-ways
2)  Creating iPhone applications that use that data;
3)  Having other web applications use that data for their own end.

Normally, I'd just create an API and be done with it.  However, this data is in fact mildly confidential - which is to say that we don't want our competitors to be able to look up all our products every morning and then automatically set their prices to undercut us.  And we also want to be able to look at who might be abusing the system, so if someone's making ten million complex calls to our API a day and bogging down our server, we can cut them off.

My next logical step would be then to create a developers' key to restrict access - which would work fine for web apps, but not so much for any AJAX calls.  (As I see it, they'd need to provide the key in the JavaScript, which is in plaintext and easily seen, and hence there's actually no security at all.  Particularly if we'd be using our own developers' keys on our site to make these AJAX calls.)

So my question: after looking around at Oauth and OpenID for some time, I'm not sure there is a solution that would handle all three of the above.  Is there some sort of canonical "best practices" for developers' keys, or can Oauth and OpenID handle AJAX calls easily in some fashion I have yet to grok, or am I missing something entirely?

Answer (score 5):

I think that 2-legged OAuth is what you want to satisfy #2 and #3. For #1 I would suggest that instead of the customer making JS requests directly against your application, they could instead proxy those requests through their own web application.

Comment: But how can this API proxy server be secured to prevent attacker from abusing it?

Answer (score 1):

A midway solution is to require an API key; and then demand that whomsoever uses it doesn't actually use it directly with the AJAX; but wrap their calls in a server-side request, e.g.:

```
AJAX -> customer server -> your server -> customer server -> user
```

Creating a simple PHP API for interested parties shouldn't be too tricky, and your own iPhone applications would obviously cut out the middle man, shipping with their own API key.

Comment: There must be a way to do it - isn't Google Analytics doing this by allowing you to paste some JS right into your page and somehow makes that secure API call?  I wonder how they do this.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth and OpenID are unlikely to have much to do with the AJAX calls directly.  Most likely, you'll have some sort of authorization filter in front of your AJAX handler that checks a cookie, and maybe that cookie is set as a result of an OpenID authentication.

It seems like this is coming down to a question of "[how do I prevent screen scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396817/protection-from-screen-scraping)."  If only logged-in customers get to see the prices, that's one thing, but assuming you're like most retail sites and your barrier to customer sign-up is as low as possible, that doesn't really help.

And, hey, if your prices *aren't* available, you don't get to show up in search engines like Froogle or Nextag or PriceGrabber.  But that's more of a business strategy decision, not a programming one.