# Filter fake traffic on site

Tags: php, apache, bots, spam, spam-prevention

Bots that mimic clicks on links come to the site. Browse the page and the like.

Their IP address is different, the User-Agent is no different from ordinary users, the countries are also different.

The only thing that gives them out is the zero activity on the site and the entry interval of all bots within an hour, in the amount of about 15 bots.

These bots can handle JC scripts, because Google Analytics accepts them as regular users. I tried to include spam bots filtering, there was no result.

Ban by IP address, by country, by browser header is not an option. How else can you track fake traffic on the site from bots and prevent them from going to the site?

Comment: When you run your Google Analytics reports can you filter out the "zero activity" visitors?

Comment: I need them to not be able to get to the site completely

Comment: Do you know what these bots are doing? Are they submitting forms or just scraping content?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34828465/2191572 because it is really a superb summation of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a CDN service such as Cloudflare.

Cloudflare (and other similar services) act as a proxy for your site, providing services like caching, and filtering of suspicious traffic.

Because they serve a lot of traffic for a lot of sites, they have a very strong understanding, in real time, of what traffic is coming from bots or hackers, and they can filter out a lot of it before it even gets anywhere near your site.

They offer a number of other benefits as well, but even if you ignore everything else, I think this kind of service is probably the only way you're going to filter out these kinds of highly sophisticated bots.

For smaller sites, you can get Cloudflare's basic service for free. Larger sites will need to pay a subscription for the service though.