# How to get data from Quizlet without getting blocked for web-scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping

So my goal is given a quizlet link (or id of the set of flashcards I'm wanting to access) to retrieve the text of the flashcards. I could've done this with their api but it seems to be non-existent now. I can also pretty easily webscrape them but worry this will break their TOS and/or possibly result in an IP ban. Is there any other way to access the data or is webscraping the only way?

Comment: What have you tried so far? `requests.get(<url>).text` using Python's `requests` library can be good start.

Comment: @DaveIdito well I would have no issues webscraping it that would be easy for me. However a lot of websites will block your ip if you webscrape without their consent so was wondering if anyone knew how quizlet expected us to access the data.

Answer (score 2):

There's no one silver bullet to solve this problem (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161548/how-do-i-prevent-site-scraping) how many potential ways are there to stop web-scraping attempts). But here are potential solutions (in increasing order of difficulty).

**1. Use proper HTTP [user-agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)**

Here's a PIP [package](https://pypi.org/project/user-agents/) that can help you manage it.

**2. Add some randomness to when simultaneous requests are sent**

Instead of running, say `requests.get(<url>)` in while loop or even in multi-process/thread, add a `time.sleep(<some random time>)`.

**3. Simulate a real browser**

You can use a WebDriver which will run and render the scraped page as if it were running in a browser (like Chromium or Firefox, etc.). You can even use in a *headless* mode; [Python Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) would be one potential choice. This way, if the Javascript itself is trying to thwart your web-scraping attempts (for instance a React-rendered page, or the Google Webstore, you won't have to worry about such things at all.

**4. Get tons of IPs**

You can buy proxy IP addresses. This would be the most fool-proof method and would be pretty difficult (or atleast painful) for a public webservice to block.

Or, combine two or more of above. From personal experiences, I've never found a single web-service that could stop web-scraping attempts. BUT, in my use cases, I'd be very careful with legal and ethical concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Use headers if you are using python requests. It will let you through the blocking.

Example :

```
import requests

headers = {
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  'cookie': 'yourcookie',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
  'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12239.92.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.136 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get('https://quizlet.com/173246204/mgmt-final-exam-flash-cards/', headers=headers)

text = response.text

print(text)
```